# Unable to Apply Shadow Mask on Mosaic

Tags: google-earth-engine, mosaic, shadow

When I visualize the `medianpixelsclipped`, it shows the images but not for the `mask_shadow`. I have written another code where I have done the same for 1 image, and `mask_shadow` is working there. But here in this code, I am also unable to calculate NDWI mask using `mask_shadow`, but it gives values for the NDWI mask if `medianpixelsclipped` are used to calculate NDWI instead of `shadow_mask`.

```
var areaOfInterest = Kenya;
// Zoom to area of interest
Map.centerObject(areaOfInterest);
Map.addLayer(areaOfInterest);

var startYear = 2023;
var endYear = 2023;


// For Shadow Masking
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');

for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  for (var month = 1; month <= 1; month++) { // Loop through all months (1 to 12)

    /*
    // Get the last day of the current month
     var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 
     for (var day = 1; day <= lastDay; day++) { // Loop through all days of the month
         var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, day);
         var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'day');
    */

    for (var day = 1; day < 2; day++) {
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, day);
      var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'day');

      // Returns all the images between the start date and the end date
      // taken on the area of interest
      var sentinelImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
        .filterBounds(areaOfInterest)
        .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);

      print("Number of images = ", sentinelImageCollection.size());
      print("Image Date:", startDate);

      var medianpixels = sentinelImageCollection.median();
      var medianpixelsclipped = medianpixels.clip(Kenya).divide(10000);

      // Map.addLayer (medianpixelsclipped, {bands: ['B12', 'B11', 'B4'], min:0, max:1, gamma:1.5}, 'Mosaic '+ ee.Date(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo());


      // Shadow masking
      var mask_shadow = cld.hollstein_S2(['shadow'])(medianpixelsclipped);

      Map.addLayer(mask_shadow, { bands: ['B12', 'B11', 'B4'], min: 0, max: 1, gamma: 1.5 }, 'Mosaic ' + ee.Date(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo());

      var ndwi =
        mask_shadow.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');

      // Create NDWI mask
      var ndwiThreshold = ndwi.gte(0.05);
      var ndwiMask = ndwiThreshold.updateMask(ndwiThreshold);

      Map.addLayer(ndwiMask, { palette: ['blue'] }, 'NDWI Mask ' + ee.Date(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo());
    }
  }
}
```